# Absolute page coordinates of metapost figures using luamplib/lualatex

Tags: luatex, positioning, metapost, luamplib

How can one draw/place metapost figure elements (using luamplib in lualatex) as if the pdf page were a graph paper? So there is origin: (xorigin, yorigin), and all the elements are placed relative to the origin or relative to each other? For instance, place a circle of diameter 2 at (3,4). Where (3,4) is an absolute position on page w.r.t origin (xorigin=0pt,yorigin=0pt would mean top left of the page). Also, numbers 2,3,4 get scaled by scale/xscale/yscale which can be in pt/cm/inch. I know it is possible to do this with tikz, though I haven't come across a post that dives into how one could do this in metapost (metapost/luamplib manual doesn't dive much in origin, and absolute page placement). I tried using [textpos](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/textpos), though that's not a real solution as let's say if I add labels to the top/left of the circle then the center of the circle shifts away from (xorigin+3*xscale,yorigin+4*yscale) on pdf page; because it is trying to align the left/top boundry of figure to the anchor point of textpos (instead of anchoring center of circle to the anchor point of textpos). And making manual adjustments would be a nightmare if the figure changes in future. A solution would provide/demonstrate a systematic way of placing any/all figure elements at absolute/relative locations on page.

> A more formal spec with an example: So for instance, after placing the circle at some absolute
>   location on the pdf page: (xorigin+X*xscale,yorigin+Y*yscale) with a
>   diameter of D*xscale or D*yscale; I would also like to position other
>   elements like labels relative to this circle at an offset of
>   (Xoff*xscale,Yoff*yscale). All the while only specifying
>   X/Y/D/Xoff/Yoff, or less preferably (but still acceptable) with the
>   multiplier *(x|y)scales.

Here's a simple figure + code to being with:

[image: example metapost figure]

```
% Command: >> lualatex abspicture.tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[paper=letterpaper,left=0in,right=0in,top=0in,bottom=0in]{geometry}
\usepackage{luamplib}


\begin{document}
\thispagestyle{empty}

\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1)
u=50;
draw fullcircle scaled u;
pickup pencircle scaled 2;
draw (u/2,0); draw(0,u/2); draw(-u/2,0); draw(0,-u/2);
label.rt(btex $\theta = 0$ etex scaled .5, (u/2,0));
label.top(btex $\theta = \displaystyle{\frac{\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,u/2));
label.lft(btex $\theta = \pi$ etex scaled .5, (-u/2,0));
label.bot(btex $\theta =\displaystyle{\frac{3\pi}{2}}$ etex scaled .5, (0,-u/2));
endfig;
end;

\end{mplibcode}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Can we assume that you want answers about how you can do this with `luamplib`?  Metapost (per se) does not really have a concept of page size; there are no commands to produce the usual EPS page management features.  But combined with `luamplib` you can make a graphic as big as you like and put it anywhere on the page.  You just need to know that `luamplib` will create an hbox which you can place using the normal box shifting features (you might find that plain TeX was easier to do this.

Comment: As for automatic scaling; you *could* write macros to do all that, but you might end up re-creating TikZ.  The main reason I like plain MP is because the syntax is simple; and perhaps because it was designed by Knuth and John Hobby who probably did a much better job than I ever could.

Comment: @Thruston Yes that’s actually what I meant: with luamplib. I’ll update the question to reflect that.

Comment: Side note: In ConTeXt with Metafun there is the concept of pages.